# objects.all().annotate results not exactly what I want

Tags: django, django-templates

Here's my code:

models:

```
class Category(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

  def get_month_sum_series(self):
    return [('2012-01-01',100)]

class Operation(models.Model):
  date = models.DateField()
  value = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 9, decimal_places = 2)
  category = models.ForeignKey(Category, null = True)
  comments = models.TextField(null = True)
```

view.py:

```
from django.template import Context, loader
from accounts.models import Category, Operation
from django.http import HttpResponse

from django.db.models import Sum, Max

def index(request):
  category_list = Category.objects.all().annotate(suma = Sum('operation__value'))

  template = loader.get_template('reports/index.html')
  context = Context({
    'category_list' : category_list,
  })
  return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

template:

```
{% if category_list %}
<table>
{% for category in category_list %}
<tr><td><a href="{{ category.id }}/">{{ category.name }}</a></td><td style="text-align:right">{{ category.suma|default:0|currency }}</td>
{% for month_sum in category.get_month_sum_series %}
<td>{{ month_sum.1|default:0|currency }}</td>
{% endfor %}
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
{% else %}
{% endif %}
```

category.get_month_sum_series doesn't work....

BUT if I change

```
category_list = Category.objects.all().annotate(suma = Sum('operation__value'))
```

into

```
category_list = Category.objects.all()
```

category.get_month_sum_series doesn't works.....
 (but the annotate part of course - not)

How to change category_list or view to get both of them?

Comment: What do you mena by "doesn't work" in both cases? If you get empty output in template, try to do same thing in shell: get queryset, get item from it, print item.

Comment: Yes, I mean empty output. And in shell I can see the correct result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. It looks like Category.objects.all().annotate is different than Category.objects.annotate - or I don't reboot apache enough time ;D